# How Do I Make Visual Studio Design Render Bootstrap Correctly?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

Excuse me, my English is bad, I'm Brazilian!!!

I'm developing a application in Aspx and WebForms. I included Bootstrap in my application, but in Design failed the rendering.

See bellow the image:

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6ADb.png)

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <header>
                <label class="hamburger" for="nav-toggle"></label>
                <input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox" class="hidden" />
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="cadentidade.aspx">Entidades</a></li>
                        <li><a href="frmusuario.aspx">Usuários</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Default.aspx">Logoff</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: This is not an answer. You need to update your question with this info. Also mention what version of Bootstrap you are using.